# cannot place button on bottom right corner

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

In scene builder preview button is on exact spot i.e bottom right corner without any gap but when i run my application there is gap.
[image: Scene builder preview]
[image: In application view]

Button is on a pane and pane is placed on top of anchor pane.
How can i fix this issue?
same thing happening with other components when i placed them on far right or far bottom.

Comment: Please provide fxml.

Comment: its almost 700 lines. can i send fxml file on your email address?

Comment: Publish it here. Fxml only.

Comment: man i tried but i cannot. its has a limit of maximum 30,000 characters when i add my fxml code it has 43,000 characters

Comment: Send it to p.krysztofiak@protonmail.com, pure text only, please

Comment: check your email

Comment: I asked for pure text fxml.

Comment: okay i copy and pasted all the code in txt file and sent your way. is that okay?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200146/discussion-between-przemek-krysztofiak-and-muzamil-mehmood).

Comment: The question as posted is not really answerable. However the use of a `Pane` indicates that you're not using a responsive layout. In some versions of JavaFX+OS combinations the scene is actually larger than the preferred size which is why using responsive layouts is of great importance. You could e.g. use the `AnchorPane` to position the button to the bottom right by adding it as child directly and specifying bottom and right anchors. Other layouts are preferable though, since `AnchorPane` does not prevent overlapping of children...

Comment: [mcve] please...

Comment: @kleopatra i tried to reproduce the problem but no such luck. everything was as it is suppose to be. Means there's something in this particular project or maybe i missed something.

Comment: @fabian i understand that, Moreover i can not achieve what i am now by adding it as child directly.

Answer (score 1):

Please examin the sample. Pay attention to min_width, min_height, pref_width, pref_height, max_width, max_height, vgrow, hgrow attributues in SceneBuiler.
The main concept is that type of pane you use sholud give you desired layout. It should not be hardcoded.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>


<HBox maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <VBox style="-fx-background-color: yellow;">
         <children>
            <StackPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Menu Button" />
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <StackPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Menu Button" />
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <StackPane layoutX="10.0" layoutY="210.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Menu Button" />
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <StackPane layoutX="10.0" layoutY="276.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Menu Button" />
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </VBox.margin>
            </StackPane>
            <StackPane layoutX="10.0" layoutY="310.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Menu Button" />
               </children>
            </StackPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
      <VBox style="-fx-background-color: red;" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <StackPane prefHeight="150.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: green;" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
               <children>
                  <GridPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" style="-fx-background-color: purple;">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </StackPane>
            <HBox alignment="TOP_RIGHT">
               <children>
                  <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" />
               </children>
            </HBox>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </children>
</HBox>
```

Comment: i understood little bit of concepts you were trying to explain with your FXML code. I also made another test project. i placed anchor pane and i used simple pane again on top of it and i added a button in bottom right corner. Now that button appear on the same exact place in both preview mode and during the execution of application. which means the pane and the container is not an issue here plus i don't need to worry about the window size. in my case it is not suppose to be flexible like yours is.

Comment: i'm still unsure about the actual problem causing my controls on pane to move on a bit left from far right side during the execution.

Comment: Use Scenic View to debug positioning of your node in runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Have you put constraints in the layout section of the button? It could be related to that. Check layout x and layout of the button and the pref size x and y of AnchorPane, if that is same, the button must be on the left-bottom corner of the pane.

Comment: i already checked there is no padding or anything. checked the pref size of x and y of anchor pane as well as the pane on top of it. i also checked the button and other controls pref size. tried to set their maximum and minimum size to pref size but still no luck